# Detect Whatsapp call and pause ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android Music Player application .I just want to pause when a call arrives , that has been acheived by the use of Telephony Manager , but i also wants to detect the Whatsapp calls and other internet calls .How to make that possible
This is my code what changes should be done to detect the internet calls also to pause the player on call and play on call ended

```
private void player_manager_on_call() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Manage player on Call

    phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
            // Incoming // call: // Pause // music
            {

                try {

                    boolean is_playing = mediaController.Check_IsPlaying();
                    if (is_playing) {
                        Log.d("xiomi", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");

                        // Get details of song from sp

                        position = PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER;

                        data = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(position);

                        Play_link = data.getPath();
                        Artist = data.getArtist() + "-" + data.getAlbum();
                        albumArt = UtilFunctions.getAlbumart(
                                getApplicationContext(), data.getAlbumId());
                        Log.e("albumArt", "albumArt " + albumArt);

                        mediaController.doPauseResume();
                        showControls();

                        // start notification service again for play

                        startNotificationService(MainActivity.this,
                                data.getTitle(), Artist, albumArt,
                                is_playing, position);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) // Not in
                                                                    // //call:
                                                                    // //
                                                                    // Play
                                                                    // //
                                                                    // music

                try {

                    if (player != null) {
                        Log.d("xiomi", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");

                        // Get details of song from sp
                        position = PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER;

                        data = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(position);

                        Play_link = data.getPath();
                        Artist = data.getArtist() + "-" + data.getAlbum();
                        albumArt = UtilFunctions.getAlbumart(
                                getApplicationContext(), data.getAlbumId());
                        Log.e("albumArt", "albumArt " + albumArt);
                        boolean is_playing = mediaController
                                .Check_IsPlaying();
                        mediaController.doPauseResume();
                        showControls();

                        // start notification service again for play

                        startNotificationService(MainActivity.this,
                                data.getTitle(), Artist, albumArt,
                                is_playing, position);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) // A //
                                                                    // call
            // is // dialing, // active // or // on // hold
            {

                try {

                    boolean is_playing = mediaController.Check_IsPlaying();
                    if (is_playing) {
                        Log.d("xiomi", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");

                        // Get details of song from sp

                        position = PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER;

                        data = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(position);

                        Play_link = data.getPath();
                        Artist = data.getArtist() + "-" + data.getAlbum();
                        albumArt = UtilFunctions.getAlbumart(
                                getApplicationContext(), data.getAlbumId());
                        Log.e("albumArt", "albumArt " + albumArt);

                        mediaController.doPauseResume();
                        showControls();

                        // start notification service again for play

                        startNotificationService(MainActivity.this,
                                data.getTitle(), Artist, albumArt,
                                is_playing, position);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mgr != null) {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

}
```

Comment: whatsapp call might be an internal state of the app, which might not be captured as a global CALL state.

Comment: `onPause` is triggered whenever your activity is lost focus , so you can handle this in `onPause` right?

Comment: @sunilsunny `onPause` method cannot handle this because if we click on home button of the phone then also this method will be invoked ,my player should be a background player also

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity if its an internal state can we find that state invocation?

Comment: i think we cannot receive this kind of broadcast because these broadcast are private to app and are not public by whatsapp developer.you can check whatsapp FAQ for more information.

Comment: @TijoThomas In that case you may need  `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` `focusChange<=0` means pause.

Answer (score 2):

I'll avoid coping code from Android documentation so i'll just give you links which should answer your question.

First you don't need to detect calls from different apps by yourself, you just need to register broadcast receiver and act on audio focus changes.

1. Here you can check it out how to handle when headphones are disconnected:
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html
2. And on link below you can see answer on your question how to handle calls and etc.
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html

Comment: this is ok.but i have used this,i need to handle the whatsapp and skype calls